# KDE: Chrome Ctrl+I keys binding does not open up DevTools

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, google-chrome

Using latest **Kubuntu KDE**, I try to open up `DevTools` in Chrome by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> as given in the Tools menu. But it does not work. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> however opens Javascript console.

Can you suggest a solution? Is there a way to find out which key binding overrides the Chrome key bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct combination is `Shift+Ctrl+I` and it is used by Kopete. You can remove the key combination by assigning `Shift+Ctrl+I` to any other action and then changing it back (See *Custom Shortcuts*, for example).

Or just use `F12`.

Comment: erm it's `SHIFT+CTRL+J` but anyhoe